# Swift language: how to continue after a guard statement?

Tags: swift

Why the `continue` is flagging an error:

> continue is only allowed inside a loop

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    guard unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] != nil else {
        unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [Int]()
        continue
    }
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you mean to resume the function, you need to use an if statement instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`continue` statement should be used in `loops`.

if you want to check multiple conditions then you should use an `if` statement instead of `guard`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot “continue” the current scope (in your case, the `addToUnloadedImagesRow(_:forLocation:)` method) after a guard statement. The guard statement's else-block **must** leave the current scope.

Anyway, looking at your code, I think you just want to do this:

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    if unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] == nil {
        unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [Int]()
    }
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `guard` you could do this:

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    guard unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] != nil else {
        unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [row]
        return
    }
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}
```

But personally in this case I'd find an `if` slightly easier to read.